# Get folder details from codebehind using jquery with Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, path, directory

I have some images on my server folder and I would like to know is there a way to get that folder path and the filenames of images in that folder.

How do I access them?

This is how my folder structure looks like:

[image]

I understood that its a security issue and so I would like to know that I have done that using server side code but I would like to get that folder from codebehind to jquery.
Is that possible?

This is how I am trying to create a folder on my server and this can be retrieved using jquery:

```
IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("Uploads/" & tempDir))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to output them in the page you are rendering.

So first you would need to build a collection of files on the server, then output that list on the page, perhaps in to a hidden field. You could then read this field using JavaScript.

Another alternative would be to enable directory browsing in IIS and then performing a GET request on that directory.

Comment: @Vince-I have updated my code can you check that and say me if it is possible?

Comment: You need to go in to IIS and enable "Directory Browsing" for that particular directory. Then using your favorite client side framework, i.e. jQuery, perform a GET request on that directory and you should get a listing. Be very careful if doing so, you don't want to expose any files that could be compromised.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your computers' files and directories from Javascript. This is a security issue. You need to use a server side language.

**EDIT:** Unless you use node.js

Comment: @elclanrs-I have updated my code can you check that and say me if it is possible?

Comment: Oh, I understand now, lol. Well, I'm not that familiar with ASP, but my guess is that you'll need get those variables in the front-end with ajax somehow...

Comment: @elclarns-Yes,I was trying to get that :)

Comment: You can output a list of files and their paths using a Hidden field, then read it in using JS and simulate remote directory browsing. Provided the directory is mapped to a virtual path, it is possible.